# How long is raw (unrendered) beef suet is good for in the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, beef, refrigerator, fat

Note that this question

- is about [suet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suet) (unrendered kidney fat from cow), [*not* tallow](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/can-i-store-suet-or-home-rendered-tallow-at-room-temperature-for-a-year).
- was never answered before on this site; [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer) specifically does *not* say anything about unrendered fats.

Therefore please refrain from closing this question as a duplicate of either of those aforementioned questions.

---

The question really is: how long can raw unrendered beef suet be left in the fridge? Suet when *rendered* is called tallow and can be left outside for about a year, but what can be said of suet when *not rendered* and left in the fridge?

Comment: Sorry, you cannot ask the same question again when your first one got closed. You would have to convince users or moderators to reopen the original one. Also, it was explained in the closure that the information in the other question applies to your case - the FDA does not issue different guidelines for different parts of the cow.

Comment: @rumtscho The FDA does not issue *any* guidelines for products of bovine origin because it's not their jurisdiction.  And OP, I saw the issue with getting your question posted up here, my condolences.  I would strongly recommend -- especially if you are trying to find out for development of a Food Safety Plan -- to post up on AskFSIS.  Although I'm not familiar with the specific product you're referring to, I'm fairly certain it falls under FSIS (USDA) arena for inspection policy and guidance.

Comment: Also, I can't post an answer since this post is marked, but there should be plenty of HACCP plans online available for you to review and conduct your own hazard analysis.  At our facility, we handle very little beef (usually raw ground, going into NRTE Not-Shelf-Stable), I can't remember the exact parameters off the top of my head.  You can follow the standard guidelines of 40°F-80°F < 8 hours, 80°F-120°F < 2 hours (Thompson), but you'd have to see what specific pathogens of concern are to narrow it down more than that (and that requires lethality treatment 165°F for Salmonella, 160°F others).

Comment: @Arctiic Thank you for taking the time to comment. This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Unfortunately this community is not friendly enough to formally allow that.